# Showing more feature attributes in Solr Highlight

Tags: apache, solr, highlight

How can I get more feature fields from Solr highlight output?
Currently the Highlight just returns the text snippet and docID.
During the indexing step I indexed the feature alongside with other fields I'd like to get back.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can specify other fields to return highlighting on using the [`hl.fl`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters/#hl.fl) parameter. For multiple extra fields, just use that field repeatedly. For example, if you want to highlight in the fields `author` and `title`, you would append

```
&hl.fl=author&hl.fl=title
```

to your Solr query. Take a look at the linked page for other highlighting options.